# Is "kviews" intentional?

Tags: support

Is the "kviews" in the image below (far right, under 3) intentional?  I'm fairly certain it's not suggesting 3,000 views.  Right?

[image: A snippet of an ELU question view, showing 4 votes, 6 answers, and 3 kviews.]

Answer (score 8):

It means 3,000 views, yes. It rounds up.

That is to say, it is 3 thousand-views, which is an arcane unit of measure that was conjured by SE.

Comment: Shouldn't it say "3k views" rather than "3 kviews" though? Or at least "3 k views"

Comment: No, it's 3 thousand-views, not 3,000 views. I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: Ah, yes, how silly of me. I think we're on the same page now.

Comment: Three kiloviews, to be more ISO-minded. ;-) I wonder if an extremely popular question might ever make it 3 Mviews, or three Megaviews.

Comment: @Janus: actually, nope. See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git?sort=votes&pageSize=50), "1.1m views". Edit: then again, on SO they have no kviews, either, for some reason. It's "Xk views". Inconsistency galore!

Comment: @RegDwigнt Everyone has "Xk views" now, [including ELU](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ftr7m.png), as of [May 2014](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232137/215040).